# Single-use object: yea or nay?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm thinking about creating some classes along a "single-use" design pattern, defined by the following features:

- Instances are used for performing some task.
- An instance will execute the task only once. Trying to call the `execute` method twice will raise an exception.
- Properties can be modified before the `execute` method is called.  Calling them afterward will also raise an exception.

A minimalist implementation might look like:

```
public class Worker
{
    private bool _executed = false;

    private object _someProperty;
    public object SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set
        {
            ThrowIfExecuted();
            _someProperty = value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        ThrowIfExecuted();
        _executed = true;
        // do work. . .
    }

    private void CheckNotExcecuted()
    {
        if(_executed) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a name for this?
2. Pattern or anti-pattern?

Comment: Why not just have a single function which accepts `timeout` as a parameter?  Also, you might be reinventing the wheel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

Comment: The example is minimalist; in the real world I'm envisioning a use case where method injection isn't a good fit. `timeout` was just the first thing that came to mind for a random property name.  Let me go Lorem Ipsum it a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a form of a [balking pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balking_pattern).

If it appears logical for your specific object to behave in this way, I don't see a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Streams behave in somewhat similar way (also their use Dispose/Close to lock them for most operations). So it is not exactly surprising pattern.